# Javascript not clearing box in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Internet Explorer, the bane of my development life, refusing again to do what other browsers seem to do effortlessly. I am trying to clear the browse code/value if the user selects a file type that isn't allowed. Works in FF but not IE 9. Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    extArray = new Array(".jpg", ".png");
    function LimitAttach(form, file) {
        allowSubmit = false;
        if (!file) return;
        while (file.indexOf("\\") != -1)
            file = file.slice(file.indexOf("\\") + 1);
            ext = file.slice(file.indexOf(".")).toLowerCase();
        for (var i = 0; i < extArray.length; i++) {
            if (extArray[i] == ext) { 
                allowSubmit = true; 
                break; 
            }
        }
        if (allowSubmit) {
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("Please only upload files that end in types:  "
            + (extArray.join("  ")) + "\nPlease select a new "
            + "file to upload and submit again.");
            document.getElementById('photobrowser').value = "";
            return false;
        }
    }
-->
</script>


    <form action="process.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formUpload">
        <label>Picture:</label>
        <input type="file" name="photo" id="photobrowser" onchange="return LimitAttach(formUpload, formUpload.photo.value)" tabindex="4">
        <input type="hidden" name="subphoto" value="<?php echo $newCount ?>" />
        <input type="image" src="styling/images/button-add-photo.png" id="subBtn" tabindex="6" />
    </form
```

Answer (score 1):

Browsers differ greatly on their restrictions with file inputs. File inputs allow the user to interact with and select files within their file system. So all browsers restrict JS from selecting files automatically. IE goes further to disallow changing the input select at all, even to a blank string. This actually makes sense since, if you are not allowing the selection of a given file, why should you be allowed to change it at all?

And, rather than validating it in JS you should be validating the files on the backend. Frontend validation is okay for ease of use, but even when it is in place there should always be backend validation. Users can simply turn off JS, use something like firebug to alter it or even (sometimes) download the file to their local machine, change it, then use it to submit to your site.

Comment: I have further validation, this is only to speed up the file selection but thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing `this` into the JS method, instead of finding it by the ID?:

```
onchange="return LimitAttach(this, this.value);"
```

JavaScript:

```
function LimitAttach(input, file) {  
    allowSubmit = false;  
    if (!file) return;  
    while (file.indexOf("\\") != -1)  
        file = file.slice(file.indexOf("\\") + 1);  
        ext = file.slice(file.indexOf(".")).toLowerCase();  
    for (var i = 0; i < extArray.length; i++) {  
        if (extArray[i] == ext) {   
            allowSubmit = true;   
            break;   
        }  
    }  
    if (allowSubmit) {  
        return true;  
    } else {  
        alert("Please only upload files that end in types:  "  
        + (extArray.join("  ")) + "\nPlease select a new "  
        + "file to upload and submit again.");  
        input.value = "";  
        return false;  
    }  
}
```

**EDIT**

This is kind of a hack, but you might want to give it a shot:

```
function checkImg(val){
  var dgr = val.value;
  dgr = dgr.substr(dgr.length-4, dgr.length)
  dgr = dgr.toLowerCase();
  if (dgr =='.jpg' || dgr == 'jpeg' || dgr== '.gif'){
     alert('image');
  }else{
     alert('not image');
     var objD = document.forms['form1'].divR;
     objD.innerHTML = '';
     objD.innerHTML = '<input id="uImg" name="uImg" type="file" class="defText" style="font-size: 10pt" onchange="javascript: checkImg(this);" size="30">';
  }
}

<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post">
  <div id="divR" name="divR">
    <input id="uImg" name="uImg" type="file" class="defText" style="font-size: 10pt" onchange="javascript: checkImg(this);" size="30">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This works in FF but not IE. It recognises the wrong file type and displays the error box but it doesnt clear the value from the text box...

Comment: Added another solution to my answer. Not the most elegant solution, but I think it will work across all browsers.